# Integral related to the incomplete beta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, expected-value, beta-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose that we have a CDF $F(x)$ and its associated pdf $f(x)$, $x\in[0,1]$.

What I want to evaluate is the following definite integral:

$$\int^1_0I_x(a,a)f(x)dx.$$

Here, $I_x(a,a)$ is the regularized incomplete beta function with parameters $(a,a)$ which is defined as
$$I_x(a,a)=\frac{B_x(a,a)}{B(a,a)}=\frac{\int^x_0t^{a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}dt}{B(a,a)},$$
for some $a>0$. For simplicity, we may assume $a$ is an integer.

My question is: **Can this integral be further simplified?** 
I've tried to solve it using the integration by parts. However, the value after the integration becomes $$1-\frac{1}{B(a,a)}\int^1_0F(t)t^{a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$$ and I don't know how to further simplify this expression..

Comment: Definitely more specifications on $f$ is needed.